# popToViewController, it isn't give me any crash but, doesn't open controllview and animating so code doesn't work

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, popviewcontroller

```
UINavigationController *loginNavCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
loginNavCon.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES;
loginNavCon.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

//I created navigationcontroller hear

PushMe *p=[[PushMe alloc]initWithNibName:@"PushMe" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

//this is a simple ControllView. there is just colour view

```
[loginNavCon pushViewController:p animated:YES];
NSArray *currentViewControllers = [loginNavCon viewControllers];
NSMutableArray *vcs =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:currentViewControllers];

[loginNavCon setViewControllers:vcs animated:NO];
[loginNavCon popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[loginNavCon popToViewController:p animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your root with:

> initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController

If you will pop, it will go back to this VC.

Comment: I did thi and NSArray *currentViewControllers = [loginNavCon viewControllers]; throw an exeption

Comment: what is the exception?